# Issues printing the wrong char

Tags: c

I've been playing around with ideas for a simple hangman program (new computer science major), and this code, while logically correct and working, prints a strange character (╠ to be exact) instead of printing an underscore(_) like it should. This only seems to happen when the "else if" statements are present. Anyone know what is causing this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

char w[13][3] = {
        { 'c', 'a', 't' }, //0
        { 'd', 'o', 'g' }, //1
        { 'r', 'a', 't' }, //2
        { 'e', 'e', 'l' }, //3
        { 'c', 'o', 'w' }, //4
        { 'o', 'w', 'l' }, //5
        { 'e', 'm', 'u' }, //6
        { 'b', 'a', 't' }, //7
        { 'e', 'l', 'k' }, //8
        { 'p', 'i', 'g' }, //9
        { 'b', 'e', 'e' }, //10
        { 'h', 'e', 'n' }, //11
        { 'f', 'o', 'x' }, //12
};

char u,
    dis[100];

int random;

srand(time(NULL));
random = rand() % 13;

printf("%d\n", random); //check random number
printf("Enter a letter: ");
u = getchar();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    if (w[random][i] == u){
        dis[i] = u;
    }
    else if (w[random][i] == '_'){
        continue;
    }
    else if (w[random][i] != u && w[random][i] != '_'){
        continue;
    }
    else {
        dis[i] = '_';
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("%c", dis[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: your `else if` conditions never happen! your array is not initialized with '_' at all!!

Comment: Time to learn how to step through  your code with a debugger.

Comment: My prof said we most likely will never get to debugging in our class this semester.

Comment: @Novaea:  You don't need your professor to hold your hand.  Start teaching yourself new things and you'll rise above your peers.

Comment: @indiv, I'm about 2 chapters ahead of the rest of the class. I taught myself strings and multidimensional arrays a few days ago. I just don't know my way around Visual Studio very well.

Comment: What @JonathonReinhart says.  Please work around the poor-scheduling of your tuition and learn to debug now.  Debugging is an essential skill that developers MUST have.

Comment: @Novaea Your professor sounds like an idiot. Yes, I said it. Debugging is just as fundamental a skill as programming in my opinion and experience, (if not more so!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of the random character is caused by:

1. `dis` is not initialized.
2. `dis[i]` is not set to `_` in couple of the clauses in the `for` loop.

In the `for` loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    if (w[random][i] == u){
        dis[i] = u;
    }
    else if (w[random][i] == '_'){
        // Missing code to set dis[i]
        continue;
    }
    else if (w[random][i] != u && w[random][i] != '_'){
        // Missing code to set dis[i]
        continue;
    }
    else {
        dis[i] = '_';
    }
}
```

**Update**

The code in the `for` loop is strange.

```
    else if (w[random][i] == '_'){
```

That conditional is never going to be true. None of the words you have in your test cases have `'_'` in them.

Based on your data, the conditional in

```
    if (w[random][i] == u){
```

or

```
    else if (w[random][i] != u && w[random][i] != '_'){
```

will be true. That means, the last clause,

```
    else {
        dis[i] = '_';
    }
```

will never be exercised.

I think your code can be simplified to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    if (w[random][i] == u){
        dis[i] = u;
    }
    else {
        dis[i] = '_';
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought dis[100] when declared was automatically set to an empty array of 100, though?

Comment: @Novaea, arrays that are defined in function scope are not default initialized. Arrays that are defined in global (external) scope and static scope are default initialized.

Comment: @R Sahu, that's actually exactly what I just tried. It makes sense, but now, when I try to loop it to go through a second time, it resets 'dis[100]'. I need the program to keep the values it took from the first loop to the second loop, and so on.

Comment: In that case, you have to keep another index, different from `i`. And set the values of `dis` using that index.

Comment: So that would be another for loop, correct? This is frying my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do that.

Comment: @Novaea, time to hit the books/tutorials, then.

Answer (score 2):

Your second `else if` statement,

`else if (w[random][i] != u && w[random][i] != '_')`

is going to be true most of the time (Whenever you don't guess the correct random letter). Since the only statement in that block is `continue;`, your `dis[i]` isn't set. Your output is printing a character which hasn't been initialized.

An alternative implementation would use (for example)

```
int hangman=0;
char u;
int maxGuesses=10;

// Seed random part

while (hangman < maxGuesses) {
  printf("%d\n", random); //check random number
  printf("Enter a letter: ");
  u = getchar();

  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (w[random][i] == u) {
      // You just guessed this letter
      dis[i] = u;
    }
    else if (dis[i] != '_') { // This requires you initialise dis[...] to '_'
      // You already know this letter
      continue;
    }
    else {
      // You don't know the letter, and you guessed wrong
      hangman++;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("%c", dis[i]);
  }
  drawHangman(hangman);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(dis[i] == '_') {
      break;
    }
    // If none are == '_', then finished?
    // Go to the end of the program
  }
}
```

Note: This will increment hangman 3 times if you guess none of the letters, and haven't managed any correct guesses yet! That might be harsher than intended, so probably a better increment system can be used - maybe a bool, initially false, set to true if you get it right? Then after your for(i...) loop, you can test and increment just once instead of within the loop.

Comment: This is all outside of my knowledge. I kind of understand the logic here, but I've never created my own function.

Comment: That's ok. I thought that you might have some sort of ASCII art in mind for your hangman, but you could alternatively just check the value, and when it exceeds some amount, print a line saying the player lost! Then you'll only need an `if` statement

Comment: I figured out how to get it to work just the way I want it to, but now I'm seeing your point about needing a better increment system. I'm trying to think of a way to do it without using a bool, as I have no idea how to do them and it seems I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: bool successfulGuess = false; and then in your first if condition, set it true, then test at the end for false.